# Bivariate normal with marginal and conditional densities

Tags: r, plot, gaussian

I am trying to create a figure in R. It consists of the contour plot of a bivariate normal distribution for the vector variable (x,y) along with the marginals f(x), f(y); the conditional distribution f(y|x) and the line through the conditioning value X=x (it will be a simple abline(v=x)).
I already got the contour and the abline:

[image: http://i62.tinypic.com/noyfls.png]

but I don't know how to continue.

Here is the code I used so far:

```
bivariate.normal <- function(x, mu, Sigma) {
  exp(-.5 * t(x-mu) %*% solve(Sigma) %*% (x-mu)) / sqrt(2 * pi * det(Sigma))
}

mu <- c(0,0)
Sigma <- matrix(c(1,.8,.8,1), nrow=2)
x1 <- seq(-3, 3, length.out=50)
x2 <- seq(-3, 3, length.out=50)

z <- outer(x1, x2, FUN=function(x1, x2, ...){
             apply(cbind(x1,x2), 1, bivariate.normal, ...)
           }, mu=mu, Sigma=Sigma)

contour(x1, x2, z, col="blue", drawlabels=FALSE, nlevels=4,
        xlab=expression(x[1]), ylab=expression(x[2]), lwd=1)
abline(v=.7, col=1, lwd=2, lty=2)
text(2, -2, labels=expression(x[1]==0.7))
```

Comment: Please provide [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that includes the code you've used so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have been helpful if you had provided the function to calculate the marginal distribution. I may have got the marginal distribution function wrong, but I think this gets you what you want:

```
par(lwd=2,mgp=c(1,1,0))
# Modified to extract diagonal.
bivariate.normal <- function(x, mu, Sigma) 
  exp(-.5 * diag(t(x-mu) %*% solve(Sigma) %*% (x-mu))) / sqrt(2 * pi * det(Sigma))

mu <- c(0,0)
Sigma <- matrix(c(1,.8,.8,1), nrow=2)
x1 <- seq(-3, 3, length.out=50)
x2 <- seq(-3, 3, length.out=50)

plot(1:10,axes=FALSE,frame.plot=TRUE,lwd=1)

# z can now be calculated much easier.
z<-bivariate.normal(t(expand.grid(x1,x2)),mu,Sigma)
dim(z)<-c(length(x1),length(x2))
contour(x1, x2, z, col="#4545FF", drawlabels=FALSE, nlevels=4,
        xlab=expression(x[1]), ylab=expression(x[2]), lwd=2,xlim=range(x1),ylim=range(x2),frame.plot=TRUE,axes=FALSE,xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
axis(1,labels=FALSE,lwd.ticks=2)
axis(2,labels=FALSE,lwd.ticks=2)
abline(v=.7, col=1, lwd=2, lty=2)
text(2, -2, labels=expression(x[1]==0.7))

# Dotted
f<-function(x1,x2) bivariate.normal(t(cbind(x1,x2)),mu,Sigma)
x.s<-seq(from=min(x1),to=max(x1),by=0.1)
vals<-f(x1=0.7,x2=x.s)
lines(vals-abs(min(x1)),x.s,lty=2,lwd=2)

# Marginal probability distribution: http://mpdc.mae.cornell.edu/Courses/MAE714/biv-normal.pdf
# Please check this, I'm not sure it is correct.
marginal.x1<-function(x)  exp((-(x-mu[1])^2)/2*(Sigma[1,2]^2)) / (Sigma[1,2]*sqrt(2*pi))
marginal.x2<-function(x)  exp((-(x-mu[1])^2)/2*(Sigma[2,1]^2)) / (Sigma[2,1]*sqrt(2*pi))

# Left side solid
vals<-marginal.x2(x.s)
lines(vals-abs(min(x1)),x.s,lty=1,lwd=2)

# Bottom side solid
vals<-marginal.x1(x.s)
lines(x.s,vals-abs(min(x2)),lty=1,lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have the function to create the marginal distribution. The figure you see posted above (that I think was created in Matlab) is the figure I'm trying to recreate in R and I don't have the code for it.

Comment: I don't mean the code, but the mathematical function to create the marginal distribution. I included a link in my code that shows the derivation of the marginal distribution for the bivariate normal, you can check it there. I guess I assumed that you understood how to calculate the marginal, you just didn't know how to code it. If you like the answer, you can click the check box to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in ggplot2, inspired in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61589781/plot-vertical-density-of-normal-distribution-in-r-and-ggplot2)

```r
rm(list=ls())
options(max.print=999999)
library(pacman)
p_load(tidyverse)
p_load(mvtnorm)

my_mean<-c(25,65)
mycors<-seq(-1,1,by=.25)
sd_vec<-c(5,7)

i<-3
temp_cor<-matrix(c(1,mycors[i],
                   mycors[i],1),
                 byrow = T,ncol=2)
V<-sd_vec %*% t(sd_vec) *temp_cor

###data for vertical curve
my_dnorm<- function(x, mean = 0, sd = 1, log = FALSE, new_loc, multplr){
  new_loc+dnorm(x, mean , sd, log)*multplr
}

##margina Y distribution
yden<-data.frame(y=seq(48,82,length.out = 100),x=my_dnorm(seq(48,82,length.out = 100),my_mean[2],sd_vec[2],new_loc=8,multplr=100))

##conditional distribution
my_int<-(my_mean[2]-(V[1,2]*my_mean[1]/V[1,1]))
my_slp<-V[1,2]/V[1,1]

givenX<-34
mu_givenX<-my_int+givenX*my_slp
sigma2_givenX<-(1-mycors[i]^2)*V[2,2]

y_givenX_range<-seq(mu_givenX-3*sqrt(sigma2_givenX),mu_givenX+3*sqrt(sigma2_givenX),length.out = 100)

yden_x<-data.frame(y=y_givenX_range,                   x=my_dnorm(y_givenX_range,mu_givenX,sqrt(sigma2_givenX),new_loc=givenX,multplr=80))

yden_x<-data.frame(y=y_givenX_range,                   x=my_dnorm(y_givenX_range,mu_givenX,sqrt(sigma2_givenX),new_loc=8,multplr=80))

###data for drawing ellipse
data.grid <- expand.grid(x = seq(my_mean[1]-3*sd_vec[1], my_mean[1]+3*sd_vec[1], length.out=200),
                         y = seq(my_mean[2]-3*sd_vec[2], my_mean[2]+3*sd_vec[2], length.out=200))
q.samp <- cbind(data.grid, prob = dmvnorm(data.grid, mean = my_mean, sigma = V))

###plot
ggplot(q.samp, aes(x=x, y=y, z=prob)) + 
  geom_contour() + theme_bw()+ 
  geom_abline(intercept = my_int, slope = my_slp, color="red", 
                                           linetype="dashed")+
  stat_function(fun = my_dnorm, n = 101, args = list(mean = my_mean[1], sd = sd_vec[1], new_loc=35,multplr=100),color=1) +
  geom_path(aes(x=x,y=y), data = yden,inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  geom_path(aes(x=x,y=y), data = yden_x,inherit.aes = FALSE,color=1,linetype="dashed") +
  
  geom_vline(xintercept = givenX,linetype="dashed")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>