# How to plot multiple density distribution vertically using R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have some scatter plots look like this:

[scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgpC2.jpg)

The X values are discrete. For every X there's some Y values. I want to plot the density distribution of Y for each X. Like this:

[density plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiBsO.jpg)

Sorry that I don't know how to describe it, so I draw it by hand. Each red line is a density curve of Y corresponding to an X value. The blue line is the trend line.

In my limited experience with R and ggplot2, I don't have any ideas how to do it. I am searching for a long time on Google but no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check out the `ggridges` package for stacked density plots. You can then use `coord_flip()` to show the plots vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: You might be looking for the [ggridges](https://wilkelab.org/ggridges/) package.

Comment: It will be extremely challenging to answer your question without a representative sample of your data.  Provide it as text by clicking the [edit] button under your post. Either copy the output of the `dput(data)` command and paste the output into your question (preferred) or paste the tab delimited data from a spreadsheet program. Please see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more information.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31796083/496488), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41082095/496488) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61590744/496488) are a few examples of such plots.